# I ran nvme format -s1 and it says success formatting namespace 1 - failed to re-read partition table

Tags: security, ssd, nvme

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 20.x and I wanted to format the entire partiion b/c I am sending this computer back.

I typed:

```
sudo nvme format -s1 /dev/xxxx
```

and it responded with after a few seconds:

```
success formatting namespace:1
failed to re-read partition table
```

Since I am logged into ubuntu and I formatted the drive that has ubuntu, how is it possible erased?

Did it actually work?

Comment: Please clarify you release, there is no Ubuntu 20.x, and only one 2020 release of Ubuntu is currently on-topic for this release - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 is what I mean, so 20.0x :)